Do Trinitarians think you could arrive at a doctrine of the Trinity through natural theology alone?
Is there any way we could come to several persons, one essence via pure logic outside of scripture (i.e. natural theology)?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I guess you might be interested in my answer to "What is the relation between the Logos in Greek philosophy and the Logos in Christianity?" - somehow some of the Greek philosophers made progress towards believing God existed in more than one person. In the answer I refer to Augustine who read and commented on their progress, and on the superiority of Christian revelation.

Short answer to a short question: No, not if we want to maintain monotheism, Jesus's deity, and the Holy Spirit's presence in born again Christians.
Various formulations of Trinitarianism (such as the Nicene and Chalcedonian formulation) IS philosophical processing of the Gospels and the OT that is logically consistent and coherent.  But we don't call this "natural theology".  Crucial data come from scriptures are needed to come up with the formulas, verses such as:

John 1:1 for the preexistence of the Son of God (the Word)
John 1:14a for the Word taking on flesh to be born as baby Jesus
John 1:14b affirming that the flesh of Jesus received the "fullness of grace and truth" from the Word to the extent of what can be contained in a human nature.
John 10:30 Christ and the Father are one is understood as Christ's divine nature and the Father's divine nature are identical, thus can be taken as a hint that they are metaphysically one as well, with Christ's human nature can be seen as the Eternal essence's "temporal effect".
John 14:15-26 where the Trinitarian definition provides a key to make sense of this passage:

v. 16,26: The Counselor (Holy Spirit) is given by the Father and remains with us forever; us being born-again Christians.
v. 18: "I am coming to you" implying that in the Holy Spirit, Jesus (and the Word) is there too.  For Catholics, "The world will no longer see me, but you will see me" implies that we see Jesus being present in the Eucharist.
v. 23: "will come to him and make our home with him" the 'our' implies that the tri-personal God (a.k.a. the Trinitarian life) is given and is residing in the soul of a born-again Christian.  Thomistic processing calls this participation of God in the "life of grace" extend our participation of God in the "life of nature" (includes rationality and conscience) that all humans (born again or not) already possess since conception.  The saved will look to participate in the "life of glory" after resurrection of the body.


Many more verses outside the Gospel of John, as St. Paul processed this wonderful Trinitarian truths in his letters.

For more resource on how to do philosophical processing without importing Neo-Platonism's teaching (but possibly only using its terminology), see the 2 Church Grammar videos introduced in my other answer.

There's a question in the header and a question in the body which are slightly different and yield slightly different answers.

Is there any way we could come to several persons, one essence via pure logic outside of scripture (i.e. natural theology)?

Sure.  I am a person and you are a different person but we are both fully human.  Different persons, one essence.

Do Trinitarians think you could arrive at a doctrine of the Trinity through natural theology alone?

No.  What we cannot do is plumb the depths of the nature of God or land on correct theology regarding same without appealing to His self revelation.  The heavens declare the glory of God (Psalm 19).  The creation clearly displays His eternal power and Godhead (Romans 1:20).
This is about as far as natural law will take us without the written Word and the person of Jesus.  Creation is supposed to make us believe that He is and that He is a rewarder of those who diligently seek Him (Hebrews 11:6).  Unfortunately, coming to God in this fashion is an act of faith and such a thing is foolishness to the natural man (1 Corinthians 2:14).
But it is not really foolishness.  God has not gone anywhere.  Man walked away from Him and if He had not reached out to us through His Word (written and made flesh) what we can know from natural law tends only towards the manufacture of false gods or the rejection of any God.
"No one comes to the Father but through me", says Jesus (the Son).  If you don't have the Son you do not have the Father.

That's not the Trinity though. That's at best the existence of God.

@eques  Clearer with the edits?

Yes. You might emphasize in your first paragraph that the "unique" detail in the Trinity is not simply "persons of one essence" but "one being" which would naturally lead towards the second part of your answer.

The New Testament shows that the first step for the Apostle Peter to start understanding the deity of Christ, was when God the Father revealed to him something of that fact. He and the other Apostles had already witnessed miraculous proof from Jesus that he was far more than just a good man. But it took till this point in time before "putting two and two together" (in our parlance) started, but not due to Peter. What point in time?
When Jesus asked his disciples who they thought the Son of man (himself) really was. That was when Peter came out with this confession, "You are the Christ, the Son of the living God." (Matthew 16:15-17) Jesus' joyous response was,

"Blessed art thou, Simon Barjona: for flesh and blood hath not
revealed it unto thee, but my Father which is in heaven." Matthew
16:17 K.J.V.

That agrees with Jesus' other statements, that a head-knowledge of God and of the scriptures is not enough; people have to 'find' Christ in the scriptures, and come to him in faith to have everlasting life (John 5:38-40). Only he leads them to the Father. Equally, only the Father leads them to Christ. And the Holy Spirit is 'the facilitator' (in modern language) who works with the three parties to bring spiritual newness of life to people like Peter.
This shows that the scriptures alone are not enough to 'discover' the triune Godhead; God has to reveal such deep things to those who come to Christ in faith. But once that miracle of grace happens, the scriptures open up to the newly spiritually alive person and they begin to 'see' the trinity all over the place.
As for "natural theology alone", well that certainly leaves humanity without excuse when it comes to confessing the reality of God, the creator. But it does not enable us to discover what God has revealed of himself through his dealings with humanity over the centuries, and particularly in sending his Son to Earth to deliberately die in order to deal once and for all with sin. For that, divine revelation is needed. It begins to be understood reading the scriptures, but that alone will not save anybody; readers have to come in faith to Christ, confessing him to be the Messiah, the Son of God. And only a revelation of the Father to the individual will trigger that.
I don't know any trinitarian who thinks others could arrive at belief in the triune Godhead through "natural theology" alone. Belief in God, yes, but even the demons believe in the reality of the one God - and shudder (James 2:19).

I'm not sure whether nature alone would be sufficient to prove the Trinity specifically, apart from the Bible, and that's a fascinating question, but I have heard a couple of interesting points on that:

Signature of the Trinity in nature: I've heard it said that God has placed His signature of the Trinity in nature at a foundational level.  Nature is made up of three fundamental things: time, space, and matter (alluded in Genesis 1:1).  And each of these three things is naturally composed of "threes."  Time is past, present, and future.  Space is three-dimensional (three axes).  Matter exists in three states: solid, liquid, and gas (e.g., ice, water, and steam).
The "problem of the one and many".  Apparently there's a philosophical discussion of the "problem of the one and of the many."  It's all far above my head to understand why there's a problem with this at all, but in any case, some Christian philosophers have proposed that the Trinity solves this problem, because God is one, and yet within Himself is distinction.  (Though that isn't precise enough to arrive at "three".)
The concept of love.  Some have suggested that if we know God is love by very nature, this implies that He is one essence but distinct Persons; because otherwise, love would not necessarily exist.  (Though again, that isn't precise enough to arrive at "three".)


Yes.
What follows is in Mathematics called an "existence proof". In an existence proof, you prove that a number or function or other mathematical construct that satisfies some criteria exists without being able to produce the thing. (It might be a very large number!) In this case, I prove that there exists an argument drawn from the observation of nature that can arrive at the doctrine of the Trinity, but I do not know that argument. I merely report that Scripture tells us that such an argument exists.

For what can be known about God is plain to them, because God has
shown it to them. 20 For his invisible attributes, namely, his eternal
power and divine nature, have been clearly perceived, ever since the
creation of the world, in the things that have been made. So they are
without excuse. - Romans 1:19-20

Is the Trinity something that can be known about God? Yes. Since the orthodox Christian church believes this doctrine, it asserts that the Trinity is something that can be known about God.
If it is something that can be known about God, then God has shown it to people.
How does Romans 1 tell us this revelation took place? "In the things that have been made", which means the material creation.
God has constructed the world to project His glory. There is some way in which His Trinitarian nature is evident in what He has created. I do not know how to argue this from Nature alone, but Jesus would. He showed the two men walking on the Road to Emmaus how the Scriptures pointed to the necessity of the Christ dying and rising again, a message they never saw there before. I believe that in an analogous way, Christ would be able to point to nature and disclose the Trinity in a way that none of us has ever seen. The alternative is to believe that the Heavens do not really declare the Glory of God, as Psalm 19 teaches.
We were made in the image of God. I imagine Jesus might begin by telling us exactly what that means...
Update:
A commenter questions whether Romans 1:19-20 extends to all things or merely God's "eternal power and divinity". I cannot prove that it covers all things, but the rest of the chapter (Romans 1:21-32) makes an argument that is solidly Trinitarian.
In a repeating cycle, Paul addresses three categories of sin:

Futile thinking and a debased mind - The Mind
Dishonorable passions and impure lusts - The Heart
Evil actions - The body

The concept of the economic trinity addresses how the three persons of the Trinity manifest themselves distinctly in how they interact with the world.
Jesus, the Son of God and the eternal Word communicates verbally. His domain is the mind and speech.
The Holy Spirit addresses the heart with its emotions, passions and desires.
The Father controls time, habits and miraculous actions that manipulate the physical world, just as we do through our body.
With this in mind, Paul is making a negative argument for the Trinity. Every aspect of a human person that should be submitting to the sovereign and beneficial authority of the Trinity has rejected God, with the diverse effects listed.
One way to analyze a machine or system is to break it and study the effects. Biologists do this all the time in experiments with animals. We understand how the body works from all the diseases that have been researched. So Paul is doing the same thing with our spirituality. The ways in which people's lives descend into disorder and death tell us about the Triune nature of God.

Romans 1 isn't saying all the things that God has revealed about himself can be shown through nature - only his eternal power and divinity. There may be hints about his Trinity in the creation, but the doctrine as a whole is not obtainable from natural revelation alone.

@curiousdannii - You make a good point. I have revised my answer to show that Paul deepens his argument by showing that among the things God has revealed is knowledge of the Trinity. He does this through negative theology, showing how our lives break down in three different failure modes, each corresponding to a different member of the Trinity that people refuse to worship.
